# My Sql Query By Array value

Tags: php, mysql

I have a data array like:

```
$skill_set=$_POST['ckbox'];
```

When I print the skill set with `print_r($skill_set);` the results are:

```
Array ( [0] => core_UniversityEngScience [1] => core_CommercialPilot [2] => core_ATC [3] => core_5yrsExpinAerodromesOps [4] => core_5yrsExpinFltOps )
```

Now i want write a query like

```
Select * from tbl where core_UniversityEngScience='yes' AND core_CommercialPilot='yes' AND core_ATC='yes' AND core_5yrsExpinAerodromesOps='yes' AND core_5yrsExpinFltOps='no'
```

Hope you got my point what i want. Please help me.

Comment: What did you tried? What is the problem?

Comment: Are you using Prepared Statement? Add the code which you try.

Comment: Actually I couldn't understand what the query should be..not important to prepared statement.

Comment: @SSopno We are not here to do your homework. Try something and we'll be glad to help. Read the following links and you should be capable of solving your problem: [1 prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) [2 pdo prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) [3 pdo execute](http://php.net/manual/de/pdostatement.execute.php)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following kind of logic to capture the variables for your sql string:-

```
$core_UniversityEngScience = in_array("core_UniversityEngScience", $skill_set)?"yes":"no";
$xxx_checkbox = in_array("xxx_checkbox", $skill_set)?"yes":"no";
// similar way for other variables and then you can use them.
```

Comment: Can u please write the full query??

Answer (score -1):

Follow the answer by nandal (which is a good "help" answer as a start) and set all the variables and the full query becomes:

```
$sql = "Select * from tbl where core_UniversityEngScience='$core_UniversityEngScience' AND core_CommercialPilot='$core_CommercialPilot' AND core_ATC='$core_ATC' AND core_5yrsExpinAerodromesOps='$core_5yrsExpinAerodromesOps' AND core_5yrsExpinFltOps='$core_5yrsExpinFltOps'";
```

Comment: You should really not support this bad practice.

Comment: How is this 'bad practice'?  It is short, and as you are controlling the data (via the 'yes'/'no' text), there is no need for going to the extra work of prepared statements.  "Bad" is in the eye of the beholder - and I, for one, don't believe in "work, for the sake of work", which is what doing prepared statements, etc. would be in this case......

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
//Just copy & paste below code & enjoyed
//suppose that your skill_test array is look like below
$skill_test = array (0 => 'core_UniversityEngScience', 1 => 'core_CommercialPilot' ,2 => 'core_ATC' ,3=> 'core_5yrsExpinAerodromesOps' , 4 => 'core_5yrsExpinFltOps' );
$var = 'yes';
$condtion = [];
foreach($skill_test as $row){
    if($row == 'core_5yrsExpinFltOps'){
       $var = 'no'; 
    }
    $condtion[]= " `$row` = '$var'";
}
if(!empty($condtion)){
   $condtion  = implode(' AND ', $condtion);
   $sql = "Select * from tbl where $condtion";
   die($sql);
}
?>
```

Comment: array(0 => '..', 1 => '..') is redundant. Aswell this whole piece of code is horrible. Utilize prepared statements properly.

Comment: Hii @Xatenev, I am already known about prepared statement. I just suggest them to make your query in this way becuse he is learner not a expert to ask these type of question. Only i suggest him in which way you have able to create your sql statement.